# class diagram sensor interface

Tags: matlab, oop, class-diagram

To organize my software better I'm starting to port my matlab functions to matlab classes and I'm struggling a bit with the oop concept.

Thats the situation:

- there are physical sensors measuring a position in various ways. Each sensor has a different calculation algorithm, but all sensors do have smiliar properties: temperature, rawData, serialNumber etc.
- I want to simulate the sensor's output (via previously saved data from a database or a csv file) or get data directly from an UART interface.
- the data format differs, but the readout functions are similar (loading columns from a csv file or from a database)
- I want to calibrate the sensors within a class "SensorToolbox". This class could be used by a GUI and shall be as generic as possible.

Here is my first class diagram attached:
[classDiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP0N6.jpg)

My main objective is where to put the "loadDataFromX" and "calibrateSensor" methods.
If I consider a sensor object representating a "real" sensor, then the sensor can not load data or calibrate itself. It's only possible via a function in the "SensorToolbox". But the calibration realization is different for each sensor. So putting the function into the toolbox would require the detection of the class type and a implementation outside the sensor.
The same applies to the sensor's data. Calling "loadDataFromFile" from the toolbox would require to know the needed dataformat outside of the sensor.

Hopefully you understand my problem and you can push me into the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put these methods into sensors. Don't worry that they don't 100% represent the behavior of the real sensor, it is just a model.

Another option is to share these methods between SensorToolbox and Sensor. For example, SensorToolbox can read the data from different datasources and then pass in to the Sensor, for example (pseudocode):

```
SensorToolbox::loadDataFromDatabase():
   database = Database()
   data = database->readData()
   sensor->loadData(data)

SensorToolbox::loadDataFromFile():
   file = File('path/to/file')
   data = file->read()
   sensor->loadData(data)
```

Same for the calibration, SensorToolbox can have this method and then just path it to the Sensor (or maybe do some preparation before it):

```
SensorToolbox::calibrate(Sensor sensor, SensorData data):
   // check the data
   // ...
   sensor->calibrate(data)
```

Comment: I've been thinking about the 2nd approach, too. The problem is, that SensorToolbox must know which data the sensor needs to calibrate. readData() can be called with arguments, e.g. the needed column headers, but the headers must be provided by the sensor object?
Another approach would be to create a dictionary like database with each sensor type and its needed data and calibration routine, but this feels a bit cumbersome? Thank you!

Comment: @user8648 When it comes to the columns, it is already Sensor's work. You can handle file / database outside of Sensor and then pass the raw data to the sensor object. Or, you can move these details into the parallel hierarchy where each sensor will have a related object like "SensorOneDataFile" which will take care of the data format details for each sensor.